# Windows Batch script copy the files modified in last x minutes

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd, scripting

I am new in scripting. I want to copy the files modified in last x minutes in a batch script.
In Linux there is a simple command to find and copy  the `.zip` files modified in last x minutes.

```
find /user/log/ *.log  -mmin -180 -type f | cut -d '/' -f 5 | xargs tar -czvf /tmp/$name.tar.gz --directory=/user/log/
```

Is there any command available in windows which can be used to copy the files modified in last x minutes

as the .log file is constantly being modified by service logs 
Or how can I use `forfiles` command in terms of minutes or hours

Comment: Simple answer, there's no command directly using batch files with cmd.exe. You'd need to retrieve the files modification timestamps, and use its poor arithmetic functions to calculate the current time minus x minutes then compare etc. My suggestion due to the difficulty would be to add the PowerShell tag to your question and take that route instead.

Comment: [Robocopy](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) with the appropriate `/maxage` parameter should do it in one shot.

Comment: @alroc, directly from the page you linked to: `/MAXAGE:n : MAXimum file AGE - exclude files older than n days/date.`, hardly what I'd consider accurate for minutes, _unless `x` in the question is a multiple of `1440`_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is relatively easy in PowerShell.

```
$ts = New-TimeSpan -Minutes 10
Get-ChildItem -File |
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt ((Get-Date) - $ts) }
```

To run this from cmd.exe you can either put the code above into a file with an extension of `.ps1` and invoke it with PowerShell, or put it into the .bat script. There are many examples of doing this on SO and around the net.

Here is a more complete script that does copying as your question asked. Once you are satisfied that the correct files will be copied, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Copy-Item` cmdlet.

```
$ts = New-TimeSpan -Minutes 180
Get-ChildItem -File -Filter '*.zip' |
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt ((Get-Date) - $ts) } |
    ForEach-Object {
        Copy-Item -Path $_ -Destination 'C:\new\dir' -WhatIf
    }
```

Comment: This command is only giving me the newly created files. I need the modified files

Comment: I just tested it and it's working fine for me, @AbuSufian. Are you sure you've copied it correctly? It filters files by modified time so there's really no reason it would only show new files unless they were the only files modified in the ten minute window.

Comment: @AbuSufian, if the items were created in the last x minutes they are also classed as having been modified during that time too, _(they were modified from nothing to something)_. If you want files created more than x minutes ago but modified within the last x minutes, then you should be more clear in your question.

Answer (score 0):

**Note** this is not an answer, it is added just as support to the accepted answer.

Here is an example of [lit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447901/lit)'s PowerShell code, *(reduced a little using aliases)*, ran directly from a batch script.

```bat
@Echo Off
Powershell -NoL -NoP -C "&{$ts=New-TimeSpan -M 180;"^
 "GCI "C:\MyDir\SubDir" -Fi '*.zip'|?{"^
 "$_.LastWriteTime -gt ((Get-Date)-$ts)}|"^
 %%{CpI $_.FullName 'D:\Backups\MyLogs' -WhatIf}}"
Pause
```

Just change the number of minutes, *(currently `180`)*, on line `2`, the source, *(`.zip` files)*, directory on line `3` and your destination directory on line `5`. If you're happy with the output, remove the `-WhatIf` from line `5` and remove line `6`.